# Polynomial map on sphere is smooth

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

This is from Problem 2 from Milnor's "Topology from a differentiable viewpoint".

> Show that every complex polynomial of degree $n$ gives rise to a smooth map from the Gauss sphere $S^2$ to itself of degree $n$.

My candidate for the desired map $f$ is the natural one: We can project $S^2\backslash\{N\}$ ($N$ is the North pole) onto the plane via the stereographic projection from $N$, do the polynomial map, then take the inverse projection. Then define $N\mapsto N$. It is clear that $f$ is smooth everywhere away from $N$.

To show that $f$ is smooth at $N$, I tried to consider the other chart of this map, by projecting $S^2\backslash \{S\}$ from the South pole $S$. If we decompose the polynomial map $P:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ to $(Q,R):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, then the map $f$ on this chart is
$$(x,y)\mapsto \begin{cases} \left(\frac{Q(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})}{Q(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})^2+R(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})^2},\frac{R(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})}{Q(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})^2+R(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})^2}\right) &\text{ if }(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
(0,0) &\text{ if }(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}.$$
Maybe we can discuss the derivatives at $(0,0)$, but I can't see a clean argument in this way. I also think that there maybe something about an analytic continuation to $(0,0)$ since the function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus (0,0)$ is rational, but I am not familiar with this type of argument.

Any help to find a smooth map/show that my map is smooth at $(0,0)$ is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting rational function is much easier to analyze in complex form, where the transition map $\tau$ between the two steriographic projections has the form $\tau(z)=z/|z|^2$, or, more simply $\tau(z)=1/\overline{z}$, where $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$. Let $P(z)=p_0+p_1z+\cdots+p_dz^d$ be the polynomial of interest (with $p_d\neq 0$), and $Q=\tau\circ P\circ\tau$. We then have
$$
Q(z)=\frac{1}{\overline{P(1/\overline{z})}}=\frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^d\overline{p}_n/z^n}=\frac{z^d}{\sum_{n=1}^d\overline{p}_nz^{d-n}}
$$
We see that the resulting function is a complex rational, and the constant term in the denominator is $\bar{p}_d\neq 0$. Clearly, then, there is no issue extending $Q$ smoothly to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will you be able to point to a result which shows that the continuation is indeed smooth for rational functions?

Comment: The basic result is that rational functions are analytic (and thus smooth) on their domain (that is, whenever their denominator is nonzero). This can be shown pretty easily using the quotient rule (which works for complex functions exactly as it does for real ones).